# PHP .rtf encoding problem with polish characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, rtf

Got a problem with replacing polish characters through php in rtf file.
I want to find tagwords in rtf file content in replace them with relevant content
So what I'm doing:

```
    // Getting rtf file content
    $content = file_get_contents('<link_to_file_here>');

    // encoding to utf-8
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');

    // replacing tagword with relevant content
    $content = str_replace('[company_address]', 'Częstochowa', $content);

    // save rtf file with replaced content
    file_put_contents('uploads/test.rtf', $content);
    
    echo $content;
```

When i check what happened with rtf file content after this code executed, i've noticed that `Częstochowa` replaced with `Cz\u0119stochowa`.
Then i open a new created rtf file in MS Word and see this `CzÄ™stochowa`.
After this i decided to write `Częstochowa` manually in rtf file and check what happens. I get file content the same way (via file_get_contents) and noticed that MS Word replaced my manually wrote `Częstochowa` with `Cz\\'eastochowa`. So i decided to do this:

```
// replacing tagword with relevant content
$content = str_replace('[company_address]', 'Cz\\\'eastochowa', $content);
```

And after this i open file in MS Word and see this `Czêstochowa`
Googled a bit and found that `ê` is character from **Unicode Block “Latin-1 Supplement” (from U+0080 to U+00FF)** with code `U+00EA` but polish characters are in **Unicode Block “Latin Extended-A” (from U+0100 to U+017F)**, so i need to encode rtf file content to it somehow
I tried a lot of things but still didn't solve the problem.
Hope on Your help. Thanks for attention.

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'ę'.encode( 'cp1250').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'ê'`…

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks. After several combinations, finally managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$string = str_replace('&#', "\\u", mb_convert_encoding('Częstochowa', 'html'));
$content = str_replace('[company_address]', $string, $content);
```